# Read and extract keypoints from folder of videos opencv

Tags: python, opencv, vision

I have a list of videos (10 sec each) in a folder and I'm trying to loop through each action video to extract keypoints and save them as json files.

```
path = "path to video folder"
for file in os.listdir(path):
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path+file)
  while cap.isOpened():
    try:
      ret, frame = cap.read()
```

I ran into a problem where the extracted data has some keypoints from other videos, and I just want to run this code, end with the stop time for the video is done, pause, start next video. How can I help correct this?

Comment: you stated what you want done. that in itself isn't a problem. what _is_ the problem and _why_ is it a problem? please review [ask] and [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process multiple videos in turn you can check the `ret` (success) value of `cap.read()` to detect the end of each file. Here is a basic example you can start with:

```
import os
import cv2


path = "videos"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    print(file)

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path + '/' + file)
    count = 0

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # check for end of file
        if not ret:
            break

        # process frame
        count += 1

    print(f"{count} frames read")

    cap.release()
```